# What's the difference between saying '我不比她差' and '我比她不差'?

Tags: grammar, difference

I have a question about making comparisons in Chinese.

What's the difference between saying '我不比她差' and '我比她不差'?

Comment: 我不比她差 I am (was) not more off(something, the mark e.g.)(wrong, deficient) than she. 我比她不差 I am more not, i.e. less off/wrong/deficient/lacking than she, , meaning of 不差 depends on context (could mean e.g. "having paid up"),
i.e. taken literally the first might mean "not worse", the second " (somewhat) better"

Comment: 不比+NP+形 not more 形 than NP，比＋NP＋不形，more not（i.e. less)  形 than NP

Comment: 形 in preceding comment stands for (predicatively used) adjective, for greater generality replace 形 by 谓语 （predicate), note that e.g. 汉语水平考试词典 classifies 差 as 动词性, NP stands for "noun phrase" (including pronouns)

Comment: when looking for examples of 比不 users might conclude我比她不差 might be part of 我比她不差(还要)好 which might itself be an abbreviation of 我不差比她不差(还要)好 which seems not to be uncommon

Comment: 不差 can mean ＂not bad; OK＂，can be used similarly as
不错，thus speaker may not think of it as negation of
something negative, and thus 我比她不差 may be quite acceptable, just as 我比她不错 may be (I am more OK than she)

Comment: Although: "the adjective used in the comparison should be positive, not negative" (see e.g. https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Basic_comparisons_with_%22bi%22) it appears that ＂不差、不错＂ are not felt to be negative.

Comment: @user6065 why not post your answer as a "answer"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging from a native speaker point of view, use '我不比她差' only.
'我比她不差' doesn't make sense in Chinese, as no one uses '我比她'+ '不' + adjective.

When you want to say 'I am better than her', say '我比她好' instead of '我比她不差'
When using '我比她' + adjective, don't use '不' in front of the adjective; native people don't understand it and don't use it like that.

When you want to say 'I am not worst than her', say '我不比她差'.

More example: When you want to say 'I am taller than her', say '我比她高' instead of '我比她不矮'

Comment: Well, I'm a native speaker as well, and I'm a Hakka, the usage of "我比她不差" may be uncommon in my hometown, but people do say so and understand. In fact, I think it's just a habit of word choosing here. 不差 ＝ as good as

Comment: @user2550062; "我比她不差" is rarely spoken in mainstream Chinese. I have never heard of people say like this in my life. Most people here are beginners to Chinese. I wouldn't recommend anyone to learn something that's not used by the majority of people.

Comment: I agree. Jay Chou's songs sometimes have this reverse order lyrics though.

Comment: why I think the statement "我比她不差" has meaning of emphasis and enthusiastic, but "我不比她差" has meaning of compromise and passive.

Answer (score 0):

我不比她差
Normal structure

我比他不差
To emphasize you are **not** less...

Answer (score 0):

The emphasis of `我比她不差` is `她`, the object to be compared.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way,

> 我比他不差 - I compared with her is not worse
>
> 我不比她差 - I am not worse than her

both are correct, but the latter sounds more colloquially correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's all the same on meaning, to understanding...

我比她差
= I'm worse than her.

我**不**比她差
= I'm [*not* (worse than her)].  --We normally use this structure.

我比她**不差**
= I'm (*not worse*) than her.